# File is created with no permision

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, nfs

I have a pretty basic scenario where my Java web application (running in a Tomcat instance) is trying to save a file on an NFS server.

For some reason, form time to time I get the files created as empty with no actual permissions associated with them:

```
ls -l
---------- 1 tomcat7 admin     0 Jul 29  1975 resources.txt
```

I imagine that this could be a bit to broad scoped, but there is no actual lead I was able to follow to get an understanding of this.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Your Java application is creating the file? Seems like it's failing at doing its job. Anything in your logs for that application? This is going to come down to classic application debugging to solve. Perhaps put a check in the application to verify the state of the file, and if it failed, retry.

Comment: Hi, @emmdee! Currently we ruled out the application as the culprit since 8 out of 10 save actions for the exat same file work as expected. The rest of them fail with the exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException(Permission denied)`